# Can I memoize a Generic Method?

Tags: c#, generics, memoization

I have 2 expensive Generic methods:

```
  public T DoStuff<T>()
  {
      //return depends on T.
  }

  public T DoStuffBasedOnString<T>(string input)
  {
      //return depends on T.
  }
```

Their return values can never vary for a given Type and string.

Is it possible to memoize these functions?

---

My starting point is a memoize function taken from here:
https://www.aleksandar.io/post/memoization/

```
public static Func<T, TResult> Memoize<T, TResult>(this Func<T, TResult> f)
{
    var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<T, TResult>();
    return a => cache.GetOrAdd(a, f);
}
```

Comment: @Sinatr sorry, the static-ness isn't (I think) at all relevant to the question. It's the generic-ness that's throwing me.

Comment: Question edited to clarify.

Comment: I ... suspect you haven't read through that in detail? That's "a generic function to memoise other (non-generic) functions", not "a function to memoise other generic functions".

Comment: There is a method which uses same dictionary for cache as yours. Not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion ... that doesn't answer this problem - the methods that are being memoised on that page are not generic?

Comment: `As a result of my decision, my code for declaring a memoized method is as follows:

public Func<string, string> WithOneInput = Memoizer.Memoize(
    (string x) =>
        {
            return String.Format("Hello, {0}", x);
        }
);` That example is memoising a function that takes an argument of type `string`, not of type `T`.

Comment: **If** you use `DoStuffBasedOnString` in a method which is also generic and has the same `T` parameter, you can just use `Memoize` directly: `var memoized = Memoize<string, T>(s => DoStuffBasedOnString<T>(s));` Otherwise, I don't know a solution. I was about to write an answer that uses a ValueTuple of `(typeof(T), string)` as the input to Memoize, but failed, since Memoize returns a lambda and C# does not support generic lambdas. Good and interesting question, though!

Comment: @Heinzi ah hah! Yes, that looks a great deal more promising

Comment: Every generic class has its own static variables.  So all you need is a static `Dictionary<string, someobject>` to memorize the someobjects.  Do so on the first call when the dictionary doesn't have the string yet.

Comment: Alas, the parent class *isn't* typed, just the method. So no good :(

Comment: I think the solution must at some level involve converting the generic type to a Type object and creating a `Dictionary<Type, [memoisationCache]>` . I'll post solution if I can get that to work.